# How To build cocos2dx using emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten, cocos2d-x-3.x

I have faced with problem when I try to build simple project from source using emscripten. Let me describe my acts step by step:

1. I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS
2. install emscripten ([I have followed instructions](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/downloads.html))
3. install cocos2dx ([I have followed instructions on the github](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x))
4. I have created new project ( I have followed instructions on github too), build it for linux and run, it work good.
5. Next step I have tried to build for web using emscripten in directory of project i have entered in console:

   cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=em++ -DCMAKE_CC_COMPILER=emcc

   make

Firstly, I have got error with CC_DLL in tinyxml2.h, I removed CC_DLL, And rerun. Then I have got error on unknown include in directory "unzip" ( I have copied zlib.h and zconf.h to directory) and rerun.
Then I have got error with GLubyte -use of undeclared identifier, I have added:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

and rerun
And Then I have got error 
use of undeclared identifier 'glDeleteBuffers'; in directory /cocos
/2d/CCCameraBackgroundBrush.cpp
and many same errors, and I do not know what to do...

Could You help me please how to fix it?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use emscripten-port of cocos2d. Just add **-s USE_COCOS2D=3** to your build.

I maintain this port, and I already ported with it couple of cocos2dx games.

Now this port is merged only to incoming branch. Also, you can run cocos2d hello world project with this command:

```
python tests/runner.py browser.test_cocos2d_hello
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
Are there tutorial how to build test project (Quick start , guide, or some sort of guide) ?

Comment: You can look at test 'cocos2d_hello' in tests/test_browser.py. Adding only flag -s USE_COCOS2D=3 should be enough to build cocos2d game source file. (./emcc -s USE_COCOS2D=3 game.cpp -o game.html)

Comment: I've tried compile (https://github.com/emscripten-ports/Cocos2d)
make -s USE_COCOS2D=3 -s STB_IMAGE=1
errors:

AR /Cocos2d/lib/linux/release/libchipmunk.a
 CXX obj/release/CCBReader/CCBFileLoader.o
In file included from CCInvocation.h:33:0,
from  CCNodeLoader.h:4,
from  CCBFileLoader.h:4,
from CCBFileLoader.cpp:1:
CCObject.h:106:39: error: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [-Werror]
 #define EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS=1 
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [CCBFileLoader.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** [libextensions] Ошибка 2

Comment: And could you tell me please, for which cocos2dx  version  port is ready ?

Comment: You do not need to compile escripten-ports/cocos2d. You should install emscripten sdk incoming, and then build you cocos2d project with emcc and flag USE_COCOS2D=3. Cocos2d version is 3.0-pre, also it works with v2 projects with little modifications. You can ask me directly by mail caiiiycuk at gmail.com